# Looking for embedded Ubuntu for a headless device with a camera and network

Tags: boot, usb, camera, embedded-system

I'm prototyping a device with a high frame rate USB3 camera (Allied Vision), which has a proprietary Linux driver. Testing it on Ubuntu Desktop shows occasional glitches. This is probably due to a large number of OS processes running in the background, which are not needed for my application. Using Ubuntu Server or booting the desktop version in recovery mode reduces the glitches. What is the way to get/configure Ubuntu for an embedded system like mine? Does Ubuntu Server or recovery mode have less running OS processes? Can I boot in recovery mode with autostart of an application? Is it possible to add 3rd party hardware drivers to Ubuntu Core, which seems to have a design suitable for my use case?

Comment: Helpful discussion of issues around adding drivers to an Ubuntu Core system: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/best-practice-of-adding-a-device-driver-for-ubuntu-core/5424 . The key point is that you must roll your own kernel snap for it, and then maintain the snap for your users. Not especially difficult once past the learning curve.

Comment: @user535733 I was afraid about the learning curve. I'm just a pedestrian Linux user.